# QVector object construction with iterators

Tags: c++, qt

Is it not possible to construct a new QVector object from iterators like C++ vectors??

```
QVector<double> new_vec(vec_old.begin()+100,vec_old.end())
```

I'm getting errors when I'm trying to do something like this.Also what is the best way to construct a new QVector object from a part of other QVector??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a work-around, you could use `fromStdVector`:

```
auto qv = QVector<double>::fromStdVector(std::vector<double>(
                         vec_old.begin() + 100, vec_old.end()));
```

Answer (score 4):

According to Qt documentation, this is not possible.

[QVector Class Reference](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qvector.html)

Answering your second question, to create a `QVector` from a part of other `QVector`, I believe the following is one of the best options:

```
QVector<double> new_vec(vec_old.size-100);
double* dt = vec_old.constData;
dt += 100; // some pointer arithmetic.
new_vec.fill((*dt), vec_old.size-100);
```

This will only copy data starting at some specified position until the end, just like you wrote.